# Как передать живой аудиопоток с javascript на python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, аудио, flask

Есть проект Flask. Надо реализовать передачу звука в живом режиме. без промежуточной записи в аудиофайл, с клиентской части на сервер (Python). Диктофон реализован на javascript (jquery). Подскажите, как это можно сделать? Как передавать аудиопоток непрерывно на сервер, при этом получая от него ответы?

Answer (score 2):

Если есть Flask, то можно для этого использовать socketIO https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

JQuery позволяет отправлять поток на сервер

**Пример**

```
$.post("/listen/url", {
    audio: /* your audio stream */
});
```

Comment: а при этом передача будет в живом режиме (непрерывная, динамическая), или на сервер передастся только то, что успело поступить с микрофона до момента запроса?

Comment: На сервер передастся то, что успело записаться с микрофона, в непрерывном режиме, т.к. это аудио поток (stream). Если нужно останавливать поток, то для начала нужно знать какого он вида. Какого вида аудио-поток вы используете?

Comment: Использую для захвата звука библиотеку javascript MediaStreamRecorder.js.

mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
mediaRecorder.stream = stream;

Comment: @МарияМамонова, следуя [документации](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder), вы можете вызвать метод "pause()" у "mediaRecorder": `mediaRecorder.pause()` - чтобы остановить, `mediaRecorder.resume()` - чтобы продолжить.

Comment: Уточню задачу: мне надо, чтобы диктофон непрерывно передавал данные на сервер. Т.е., пользователь говорит, говорит... и всё это течет в python, где работает pocketsphinx livespeech, который будет распознавать речь и выводить на страницу результат, без всяких пауз в этом процессе, дабы не упустить ни слова от пользователя